# If $A^{\wedge}$ is the completion of a local ring, do we always have $\mathfrak{m}^{\wedge}=\mathfrak{m}A^{\wedge}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and let
$A^{\wedge}$ be the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion of $A$. Then $A^{\wedge}$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}^{\wedge}=\ker(A^{\wedge}\to A/\mathfrak{m})$. In the case of the $p$-adic numbers, we have
$$ \mathfrak{m}^{\wedge}=\mathfrak{m}A^{\wedge}. $$
Does this equality always hold?

Comment: Are  you sure you typed that equation right?

Comment: @SamCassidy Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Anyway it seems like your question is answered on page 109 of Atiyah-Macdonald. It holds if A is Noetherian.